# Sufficient statistics and the Rayleigh distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are iid random variables from a Rayleigh distribution with parameter $\theta$. The pdf of $Y$ is:

$$f(y; \theta ) = \begin{cases} \frac{2y}{\theta}e^{-y^2/\theta} & , & 0 < y < \infty
\\
0 & & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n y^2$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

I know that I need to use the likelihood function, and that will be:

$$\frac{2^n}{\theta^n}e^{-(\sum_{i=0}^n y^2)/\theta}$$

But, I don't know how to factor this correctly to give me my $g(u)$ and $h(y_1\text{ to }y_n)$.  At first, I split the exponential part, but that put my sufficient statistic in the $h(u)$, whereas I need it in the $g(u)$.

Comment: you seem to have some gaps where you haven't used $\LaTeX$ right, you may want to try again, just to make it look more appealing for others to answer.

Comment: It appears someone came through and fixed it for me, so thanks to whoever that was. First time trying to use math writing software/code on in the internet, so apologies on that end.

Comment: (You're welcome....)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your likelihood function should be $$\frac{2^n \prod_i y_i}{\theta^n}e^{-(\sum_i y_i^2)/\theta}$$

You want to split this into something looking like $h(\mathbf{Y})\,g(\theta, T(\mathbf{Y}))$, so you could try for example $h=2^n \prod_i y_i$ and $g=\frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-(\sum_i y_i^2)/\theta}$

Comment: Ah! I see I didn't include the product rule into the likeihood function, thanks! And that solves it. And, the reason we don't include 2^n in g(u) is because it's not in the pdf of a Rayleigh distribution?

Comment: Any piece of the likelihood expression that has $\theta$ attached (that you cannot pull apart) goes into your $g()$ function. Everything-else goes into $h()$. Sometimes $h()$ might simply be $1$. It doesnt really matter whether $2^n$ is in $g$ or $h$ because it is a constant.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer: Yes.  Indeed likelihood functions are only really defined up to a constant of proportionality so you can do what you like with the $2^n$ including losing it altogether